# Terraform AWS IAM Policy Data Source Lookup from Partial Name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to get a data source for an iam_policy that exists in all environments but has a random string appended to the end

```
DataDogIntegration-DatadogAWSIntegrationPolicy-<random-gibberish>
```

Is there anyway to get the arn for that policy based on the start of the name?
I've tried filters but they are not supported on iam_policy data sources

I've also tried these in addition to filters

```
data "aws_iam_policy" "example" {
#  arn = "arn:aws:iam::${local.account_id}:policy/DataDogIntegration-DatadogAWSIntegrationPolicy-*"
  name = "DataDogIntegration-DatadogAWSIntegrationPolicy-*"
}
```

Comment: The AWS API does not seem to support those kind of name filters for this endpoint.

Comment: What I do for similar is use a cloudformation data resource to lookup the cloudformation outputs from the datadog stack.

Comment: @MattSchuchard some data sources just use the list API endpoint and then filter internally where some things don't expose a way to search on the API itself. In fact, the existing `aws_iam_policy` data source just uses the list API endpoint and then finds all matching ARNs or policy names and if there's only one then returns that, erroring if there's more matches. It could take a parameter to do a regex match instead but it doesn't currently support it.

Comment: @jordanm if the OP confirms that the DataDog things were created via CloudFormation then it might be worth writing that up as an answer?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Seems like I made a poor assumption there. So I guess the name filtering could be added to the responsible `READ` function backing this `data` in the provider like you describe, but probably the demand does not really exist for that functionality.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR not sure if they were created by cloudformation, another team handles environmental stuff like this which is why i have to do a lookup as they didn't make a standardised name -_-

i realised after i stopped working yesterday that it might have been made by cloudformation and hence i may be able to get the name from an output from the stack that made it, but i need to go have a look to find it, will let you know once i've checked

Comment: So looks like the policy was created by a CF Stack that should have a corresponding one in all our accounts

DataDogIntegration is the stack and the resource logical id is DatadogAWSIntegrationPolicy, there are no outputs, i'm going to go away and see if there's a way to refer to resource logical ids in terraform

Comment: Created a datasource on the cloud formation stack but unfortunately i cant reference the resource

Comment: Similar to Terraform modules, a CloudFormation Stack has [Outputs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/outputs-section-structure.html) to explicitly expose values for external consumption. If the CloudFormation stack uses those then you can retrieve them using data sources in Terraform; if not, you'd need to add that as an output on the stack, which would then represent an explicit interface between the CloudFormation stack and your Terraform configuration.

Comment: @MartinAtkins as mentioned above the stacks have no outputs which is annoying, i've asked the appropriate team to add them and they've added the task to their backlog but that will probably take months. So in the mean time i'm resorting to hard coding all environments on an adhoc basis -_- in the module. It's annoying that the cloudformation stack data source doesn't allow reference to resources for informational purposes, as you can access such data trivially in the console.

Comment: Seems like [someone requested that in 2017](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/279) but it wasn't a popular suggestion at the time so it ended up being closed due to being stale. If the information you want is available from the Cloudformation API then you could open a new issue in that repository to record your use-case.